# How long can you soak morel mushrooms before they go bad?

Tags: storage, mushrooms

We got some morels from a friend and soaked them in salt water in the fridge. That was Friday. It is now the following Thursday, and we just took them out of the water and cut them down. Bad memory! The water was getting pretty brown but wasn't cloudy. Did the sniff test, and they smell like salt, but I don't know if mushrooms would have a rotten smell anyway. The consistency feels fine. Put them in the fridge in an open bag. Should I throw them away, or will they be okay? Are there any ways to know if morels are getting rotten?

Comment: Are we talking about fresh or dried morels here? (I'd dump both, tbh.)